# Fundamental Group of Klein Bottle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $C^{*}=C \setminus \{ 0 \}$.  What is the fundamental group of $C^{*}/H$, here $H=\{\psi^n;n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ with $\psi(z) = 2 \bar{z}$?

Comment: $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ tip: It's `\mathbb{C}` (or `\mathbb C` if you want to save a character): $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $\gamma(t) = e^{2 \pi i t}$ be a loop (with base point $1+0i$) representing the generator for $\pi_1(C^*)$, you get the presentation
$$\pi_1(C^*/H) = \langle \gamma,\psi \,\, | \,\, \psi \gamma \psi^{-1} = \gamma^{-1}\rangle
$$