# Fundamental group of C*/G

Tags: algebraic-topology

Find the fundamental group of the orbit space $\mathbb{C}^\ast /G$
where $\mathbb{C}^\ast =\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ 0\}$ and $G=\{ \varphi^n:\varphi(z)=2\overline z, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.
This question has a solution here [Fundamental Group of Klein Bottle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756317/fundamental-group-of-klein-bottle)
. But I didn't understand the explanation also why $\mathbb{C}^\ast /G$ is klein bottle.

I have calculated fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}^\ast /H$ where $H =\{\varphi^{2n}:\varphi(z)=2\overline z, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. But I don't know how to calculate for $\mathbb{C}^\ast /G$

Comment: What is your question? Why $\mathbb{C}^\ast /G$ is the Klein bottle? Or how to calculate $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\ast /G)$? For the latter it would be helpful to include your calculation of $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\ast /H)$, since you should be able to adapt the calculation to $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\ast /G)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I see it.

First, the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on itself by group automorphisms via the formula
$$
n\cdot m = (-1)^n m,
$$
so we can construct the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ which as a set is just the cartesian product $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and where the composition law is given by
$$
(m,n)(m',n') = (m+n\cdot m',n+n') = (m+(-1)^n m',n+n').
$$
Now, the group $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{C}$ by the formula
$$
(m,n)\cdot z = \psi^n(z) + 2\pi i m
$$
where $\psi(z)=\log(2)+\overline{z}$. Also, $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^*$ via the formula
$$
(m,n)\cdot z = \varphi^n(z),
$$
and the exponential map $\exp:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^*$, $z\mapsto e^{z}$ is equivariant under this action. Now it is easy to see by construction that
$$
\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{C}^*/G,
$$
and since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected we have that it is the universal covering space of $\mathbb{C}^*/G$ (since the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}^*$ and of $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{C}$ are both properly discontinuous). Thus
$$
\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^*/G,\tilde{1}) \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}),0) \cong \mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z},
$$
where the last isomorphism is given by the monodromy map, and $\tilde{1}$ denotes the $G$-orbit of $1$.

Now, note that if $p:\mathbb{C}^*\to \mathbb{C}^*/G$ is the natural quotient map, and
$$
B = \{z\in\mathbb{C}^* \; | \; 1/8\leq |z|\leq 1\}
$$
then we can easily see that every $G$-orbit meets the set $B$ and so $p(B) = \mathbb{C}^*/G$, so that $\mathbb{C}^*/G$ is compact. Since $\mathbb{C}^*$ is a $2$-manifold and the action of $G$ on it is properly discontinuous, then $\mathbb{C}^*/G$ is a compact $2$-manifold. Thus by the classification of compact surfaces without boundary, we can see, by looking at fundamental groups, that $\mathbb{C}^*/G$ must be homeomorphic to the Klein bottle.